# Getting the numbers 1-5, no matter what number it is

Tags: swift

Sorry my question wasn't very clear.

I'm iterating through number (`[1...50]`) and the results should be like:

```
1 % 5 = 1
2 % 5 = 2
3 % 5 = 3
4 % 5 = 4
5 % 5 = 0  // I want this to be 5

...

10 % 5 = 0 // I want this to be 5 as well
```

Comment: Add 1 to your result.

Comment: `print((number % 5) +1)`. That's the principle of `%` (modulo).

Comment: Why don't you use `var number = Int.random(in: 1...5)`?

Comment: Sorry my question isn't very clear. in my code number actually isn't random, and it keeps increasing.

Comment: add an example of what you need

Comment: `(number - 1) % 5 + 1`

Comment: no conclousion from your current code , what about 18 , 20 , 9  ,11  ??

Comment: @JohnMontgomery: thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>*simple code* is</strike>

```
let number = Int.random(in: 1...5)
print(number)
```

or

```
let number = Int.random(in: 1...100)
print(number % 5 + 1)
```

To get the desired result after you edited the question use

```
(number - 1) % 5 + 1
```

as suggested by John Montgomery in the comments.

Comment: Sorry my question isn't very clear. in my code `number` actually isn't random, and it keeps increasing.